# Python: rearranging an array of strings

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm trying to rearrange the following array of strings:

```
myString =['000', ['1', 'two', 'three'], ['1', 'b', 'c']]
```

So that myString2 looks like

```
myString2 = [['000', '1', 'two', 'three'], [['000', '1', 'b', 'c']]
```

Looking around for some ideas (e.g. [here](http://jpython.blogspot.de/2010/08/string-array.html)) I attempted the following loop:

```
myString2 = []
for i in range(0,len(myString)-1):
    myString2 [i].append(myString[0])
    myString2 [i].append(myString[i])
```

But I get an error which I don't really understand :

> IndexError: list index out of range

I'm fairly new to python and wonder if there is perhaps a simpler way than my current idea, and if not, if someone could kindly explain what is preventing the loop from running.

Comment: Second nested expected should start with only a single bracket.

Comment: I think you need to give more details as to what you are trying to accomplish, and the sorts of inputs you are expecting. It's difficult to give some sort of general solution without you elaborating a bit. For example, do you expect to deal with something like `['000', ['1', 'two', 'three'], ['1', 'b', 'c'], '001']`, and if so, what output do you expect?

Comment: Also your "attempt" will get a `NameError` before anything else as posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet of code you provided cannot work because of variable names, so I won't try to explain you what's wrong with it further.

That said, those problems can be easily done in one-liners using list comprehensions:

```
myString =['000', ['1', 'two', 'three'], ['1', 'b', 'c']]

new_string = [[myString[0]]+s for s in myString[1:]]

print(new_string)
```

just create a new list of lists, with the first element as head, and the rest as tail.

Results as:

```
[['000', '1', 'two', 'three'], ['000', '1', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: Great one liner! Thanks for seeing through the typos in the variables, this was exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

You were close with your script, this works:

```
myString =['000', ['1', 'two', 'three'], ['1', 'b', 'c']]
myString2 = []
for i in range(1,len(myString)):
    myString2.append(myString[0])
    myString2.append(myString[i])
```

What was wrong?

- `myString2[i].append` attempts to append something at `myString`, index `i`, so at first iteration it tries to access `myString[0]` but `myString` is still empty, that causes the out of range error. Instead use `append` just on the list and it will add the element at the last position
- you need to loop from the second element `range(1,...`
- range is exclusive, so a `range(1,5)` is `[1,2,3,4]` -> you don't need to substract 1

Comment: upvote for taking the time to understand the OP code issue :)

Comment: Yes thanks, this is very helpful! So now I know a new way for a clean one-liner, and also understand the logic of my heavier code :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use the first list to hold the string `0000`, why not put it in a constant instead

`MAGIC_STRING = '0000'`

and then simply use the constant to create the new, modified sublists:

```
myString = [['1', 'two', 'three'], ['1', 'b', 'c']]
myString2 = [[MAGIC_STRING] + el for el in myString]
```